# Web Scraping using excel Visual Basic Scripting

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

My VBA code is working for the status field for web scraping data from the website as shown in a snap. I am able to acquire all data except that address/location yellow highlighted in the snap. It needed to be added in column "E" from the website for each individual access code(password). I am attaching the current output as well. Any help would be great as I am new to scraping. Here is the image of address/location field which I need in column E. (Access codes are in column C)
Here is the image of sample[image]

Here is my VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetStatus()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object, colourLkup As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, senhas(), i As Long, results()

Call CopyCommentText
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client")
    senhas = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row))

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(senhas))

    Set colourLkup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    colourLkup.Add "active1", "green"
    colourLkup.Add "active3", "orange"
    colourLkup.Add "valid", "valid"

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    For i = LBound(senhas) To UBound(senhas)
        If senhas(i) <> vbNullString Then
            With xhr
                .Open "POST", "https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/Home/GetEstadoProcessoAjax", False
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                .send "SenhaAcesso=" & senhas(i)
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            Dim nodes As Object, classinfo() As String

            Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".active1, .active3")

            classinfo = Split(nodes(nodes.Length - 1).className, Chr$(32))
            results(i) = Replace$(classinfo(1), "step", vbNullString) & "-" & colourLkup(classinfo(2))

 End If
        Set nodes = Nothing
    Next
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)

ErrHandler:

'Error No. 1004 occurs in this case if worksheet with the same name already exists

If Err = 91 Then

'MsgBox "Invalid Code" & Chr(10) & Sheet1.Cells(i + 568, 4).Value & " " & "Row" & i + 568
classinfo(1) = "Invalid"
classinfo(2) = "Valid"


Resume Next
End If

Call CopyCommentText

Call Copy_With_AutoFilter1

End Sub
```

Here is the output I have made access codes to hide as it is confidential.
[image]

Comment: @QHarr can you please help

Comment: Are you trying to send data to them or get data from them? You are using .Open "POST"

Comment: yes i send data and then receive data

Comment: It takes access codes as password input in the web, and then fetch results

Comment: OK, but using POST means you update their data. I think you should use GET command.